# Microsoft SQL Jdbc Driver dependent code is not working when converted to jar file

Tags: java, jdbc, jar, java-8

I am using Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver to insert student registration fields for learning purpose to database.I had created that **java application sucessfully and that application is working fine** **when I am running it as a java program.**
Now I converted that Java program to jar file while converting Java program to jar file I took all precautions like copying external jar files to lib folder and to provide Native library path to Jdbc driver jar file.
But still **when I am running my jar file I am getting the following set of errors**, please guide me:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at bean.DbConnectClass.jdbcConnction(DbConnectClass.java:16)
        at Main.main(Main.java:21)
```

Please note that I am using Java 8 version and I am currently using compatible version of jar file.

My Manifest file contains the following:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Main
```

My code is as follows: **I am just calling this class by main method by passing parameters to created jar file.**

```
public class DbConnectClass {
    Connection connection = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    public void jdbcConnction (){
        try{
        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            **System.out.println("Where is your MSSQL JDBC Driver?");**
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("MsSQL JDBC Driver Registered!");
        try {
            connection = DriverManager
            .getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;instance=DELL\\HOME;DatabaseName=Prime_Student","confidential", "confidential");
            //jdbc:sqlserver://10.105.219.102:1433;instance=OVOPS;DatabaseName=openview;inte‌​gratedSecurity=true

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        if (connection != null) {
            stmt = connection.createStatement();
            System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
        }
        }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    public String insertUpdate(String id,String time,String location,String StudentName,String Description,String TeacherName,String SubjectTxt,String Room_Id)
    {


            CallableStatement cstmt = null;
             try {

                    System.out.println("Going to insert the data");
                 cstmt = connection.prepareCall(
                            "{call insert_to_Load_StudentData(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}",
                            ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                            ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

                    cstmt.setString("parm1", id);
                    cstmt.setString("parm2", StudentName);
                    cstmt.setString("parm3", location);
                    cstmt.setString("parm4", Description);
                    cstmt.setString("parm5", TeacherName);
                    cstmt.setString("parm6", SubjectTxt);
                    cstmt.setString("parm7", time);
                    cstmt.setString("parm8", Room_Id);
                    boolean results = cstmt.execute();
                    //int rowsAffected = 0;
                    if (results==false)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Data Inserted sucesfully");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Data is inserted properly");
                    }
            //ResultSet rs = null;


        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
    public void closeConnection (){
        try{
            connection.close();
            stmt.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
        }
    }
    }
Modified Manifest File

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Main
Class-Path: . sqljdbc4.jar
```

I also tried to run the below command:

```
jar -cvfm jarfilename.jar manifest.mf *.class
```

**but its showing not recognized batch command then I modified this command as**

```
 java -jar -cvfm jarfilename.jar manifest.mf *.class
```

errors coming with above command is

```
Unrecognized option -cvfm
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine
Error: A fatal exception has occurred Program will exit.
```

Please guide me on the same,Please note that even still on doing modification on Manifest.mf exceptions are kept coming.

Comment: `"Where is your MySQL JDBC Driver?"` -- this looks like your own error message, one you've got in your own code, not a message from the JVM. Where is your pertinent code, the code that throws this exception?

Comment: The SQL Server JDBC JAR is not on your classpath, despite what you may think.  Can you show us your project structure?

Comment: Also did you create a proper manifest file for your jar file, one that can find the database? One that puts the db jar file in the `Class-Path:`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I have provided my manifest file attached

Comment: Then that's it. Your manifest is plainly deficient and does not have the necessary Class-Path: statement.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels that question belongs to MySQL by mine question belongs to mssql although I will try to get help from that but if possible please remove duplicate

Comment: It doesn't matter what database or resource you're using, whether it's MySQL or MS SQL, or FubarSQL. If you want to use another jar file, you must reference it in the manifest. Period. Full stop.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  I also attached the code since I am also getting exception in the code and in your provided question there was no mention of exceptions that I am getting here

Comment: And as I predicted, the error message that was confusing you was coming from your own code! `System.out.println("Where is your MySQL JDBC Driver?");`

Comment: First **fix your manifest**, and only then come back and say that it's not a duplicate.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I modified the manifest.mf file as suggested and re-created the jar files and re-run the jar file still the error is coming please have a look and remove the duplicate Thanks

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels my manifest.mf file is edited as per best in my knowledge and please also go through the question I accepted that error "Where is MySQL driver is due to my code" now please remove the duplicate from the question ,

Comment: Please show your latest manifest -- that's the only way of knowing if its been fixed.

Comment: And note that your current error messages have nothing to do with the database -- you appear to be trying to run the program incorrectly. What's with that?